# How properly to use bootstrap-vue's panel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to migrate my project from vue-strap to bootstrap-vue. I have trouble to migrate [panel](https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/). The current vue-strap code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <panel is-open type="info">
        <table slot="header"><th>Search:</th></table>
        <search-form :fieldList="fieldList" :customs-max-num="customsMaxNum" :data-types="dataTypes" />
    </panel>
</div>
```

The `search-form` is my component. As I understand, I need to use the collapse of bootstrap-vue (without actually collapsing), as shown in the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/#accordion-support). But it looks like every variant of code I tried, did not work. What is the proper way to use the vue-bootstrap's panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Header (button that opens the panel) is composed by:

```
<b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
   <b-button block href="#" v-b-toggle.accordion-2 variant="info">Accordion 2</b-button>
</b-card-header>
```

The **b-button** component have a directive **v-b-toggle.*accordion-2*** and it's call the  **b-collapse** component with **id = *accordion-2***.

Inside the component **b-card-body**, you can pass your component (like a children). See the sample:

```
<b-card no-body class="mb-1">
  <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
    <b-button block href="#" v-b-toggle.accordion-2 variant="info">Click Here</b-button>
  </b-card-header>
  <b-collapse id="accordion-2" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
    <b-card-body>
      <search-form :fieldList="fieldList" :customs-max-num="customsMaxNum" :data-types="dataTypes" />
    </b-card-body>
  </b-collapse>
</b-card>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! I have imported `VBToggle` but I get `Failed to resolve directive: b-toggle`. Do you know maybe why?

Comment: `import { VBToggle } from 'bootstrap-vue'; Vue.directive('b-toggle', VBToggle);`

Comment: Or: `import { CollpasePlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'; Vue.use(CollapsePlugin);`

Comment: I see thank you. It looks like it does not create the borders. Should there be some class for that?